# Issue signing jar for Android app in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar-signing

My understanding is that if you Export -> Export Android Application in Eclipse and follow the creation of keystore and alias, the Android app will be ready to uploaded to Google play (it will be signed and zipaligned).

I did the above and then ran:

```
  jarsigner -verify my_signed.apk
```

and got the following:

```
  jar verified.
  Warning:
  This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.
```

Any ideas? When I download the app from the market, I get "classnotfoundexceptions" but the app works fine when I run it from Eclipse (AVD or on my android). Could the verification issues be the cause of that too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "ClassNotFoundExceptions" are most likely a result from Proguard. In other words if you are using proguard certain Classes must retain their name and not end up obfuscated.

When you run your app from Eclipse the apk file which is build is NOT obfuscated.

Look here : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

" The default proguard.cfg file tries to cover general cases, but you might encounter exceptions such as ClassNotFoundException, which happens when ProGuard strips away an entire class that your application calls."

And also run jarsigner as follows : jarsigner -verify -keystore

Answer (score 0):

Right mouse-click your project,
select "Properties",
select "Java Build Path",

Make sure you have "External Dependencies" checked  in the "Libraries" Tab.

Comment: I don't see that as an option. In the Libraries Tab: I have Android Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

The last time I've faced this problem I figured out that I was using `keytool` and `jarsigner` from different versions of JDK.

Make sure you are not doing the same and your APK will be okay.

Let me know if it works to you.

Comment: I only have one JDK installed: C:\Program Files\Java. I see JDK 1.7. I see two versions of JRE

Comment: @emily, What's your JRE's version?

Comment: I guess with a JDK 1.6 you could solve the issue. If you are not using `keytool` and `jarsigner` from different versions of JRE then I'm affraid I cannot help you more! :/